# How to prove $a^{1729}\:=_{1729}\:\:a$? I know it's a Carmichael number, but how can we show it directly without knowing it's a Carmichael number?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I already proved it if $1729$ divides $a$, or if it doesn't divide $a$ but it's Greatest Common Divisor is not equal to $1$ (we get that the left side is equal to $0$ and the right side is equal to $0$ thus in these cases $a^{1729}\:=_{1729}\:\:a$ is a true statement).

But I can't find a proof for $1729$ does not divide $a$ and it's Greatest Common Divisor is equal to $1$.

Comment: What does it mean $$a^{1729}\:=_{1729}\:\:a$$

Comment: $a^{1729}=a\:mod\:1729$

Comment: What does ‘it's Greatest Common Divisor is (or not) equal to $1$’ mean?

Comment: Greatest Common Divisor = c, then c is the biggest integer which divides both (here) 1729 and a

Comment: What's the prime factorization of $1729$...

Comment: 7 * 13 * 19 = 1729

Comment: "7 * 13 * 19 = 1729"  SO..... Chinese remainder theorem....

Comment: More generally, using CRT, we can show that $a^n\equiv a\pmod n$ for any squarefree $n$ and $\gcd(a,n)=1$

Comment: As in the linked dupe, it suffices to show that $1729$ is squarefree, and for each of prime  $\,p\mid 1728\,$ we have $\,p-1\mid 1728,\,$  i.e. $\,6,12,18\mid 1728,\,$ true by $\,36\mid 1728\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

$1729 = 7*13*19$ and $a^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ so $a^{7*13*19}\equiv a^{1*1*1}\equiv a\pmod 7$.

And $a^{12}\equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ so $a^{7*13*19}\equiv a^{7*1*7}\equiv a^{49}\equiv a^{48+1} \equiv a \pmod {13}$

And $a^{18}\equiv 1 \pmod {19}$ so $a^{18}\equiv 1 \pmod {19}$ so $a^{7*13*19}\equiv a^{7*13*1}\equiv a^{91}\equiv a^{90 + 1}\equiv a \pmod{19}$.

So by Chinese Remainder Theorem $a^{1729}\equiv a \pmod{7*13*19}$.

Comment: Nice proof but you  don't really need CRT in your last step.

Comment: Why the CRT? We learned it that way that CRT is about that if you got a liniear system of equations in different modulos then there exists a solution to it. So I don't see the link here

Comment: @anon: fleablood is using CRT on the linear system $x\equiv a\pmod{7,13,19}$ (three congruences with the same residue with different modulos: 7,13 and 19). But we don't really need CRT here: $7,13,19$ all divide $a^{1729}-a$ and since they are pairwise coprime, their product divides it too.

Comment: @anon Note that this is simply a special case of the proof in the linked dupe. The general case is no harder, and makes it clearer how it works in general. You can find many worked examples in the links at the dupe.

Comment: @anon CRT does provide a solution as well so there is a link. Here you don't need it because all remainders are the same.

Comment: Ok I see it know, thanks

Comment: $x \equiv a\pmod {p,q,w}$ can be solved by $x \equiv a \pmod {pqw}$ but CRT remainder tells us this is the only solution.

Comment: What's the "dupe"? I've read it several times but don't know what do you mean by that

Comment: @anon Follow the link in your question to the duplicate. We already have *hundreds* of questions on this topic. There is nothing novel that can be added. It's best for the health of the site that if one deletes dupes of such FAQs (and does not answer them unless there is something nontrivially *novel* that can be said).